# List all keys with SHA-1 in the gpg keyring

Tags: security, gpg, hashsum, maintenance

After reading a paper about "[First Chosen-Prefix Collision on SHA-1 and Application to the PGP Web of Trust](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/014)", I wonder how many SHA-1 keys are left in specific key rings.

How to list all keys in a gpg key ring, which use `SHA-1`?

Comment: The command `gpg2 --no-default-keyring --keyring <file> --list-keys` maybe of some help. Seen [here](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2010-June/038847.html).

Comment: @PauloTomé this would list **all** keys, not just the keys with `SHA-1`.

Comment: Is this related to [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/014) by any chance?

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes. While there is technically no direct link to the paper, it made me to think about this question. I have added the link to the paper in the question. I did not in the first place, because I do not want to discuss the paper.

Answer (score 2):

To get the details of hash algorithms nominated for use with a particular key, edit the key, and then show the key's preference list:

```
gpg --list-keys
```

Get the key fingerprint that you want to query, and then edit to query the key prefs:

```
gpg --edit-key <key fingerprint>
gpg> showpref
[ unknown] (1). Bob Smith (GPG Key) <bob@smith.domain>
     Cipher: AES, CAST5, 3DES
     Digest: SHA1, RIPEMD160
     Compression: ZLIB, ZIP, Uncompressed
     Features: MDC, Keyserver no-modify
```

You can control the hash used for key generation at the command line, for example, with "--cert-digest-algo SHA512" and "--s2k-digest-algo SHA512". See the man page for more details.

You can also change you default preferences. "gpg --version" will show your current settings. Edit gpg.conf to explicitly remove SHA1 for future default key creation of setpref resets:

```
personal-cipher-preferences AES256 TWOFISH AES192 AES
personal-digest-preferences SHA512 SHA384 SHA256
personal-compress-preferences ZLIB BZIP2 ZIP
```

From the man page:

> showpref
>
> More verbose preferences listing for the selected user ID.
> This shows the preferences in effect by including the implied
> preferences of 3DES  (cipher),  SHA-1  (digest),  and Uncompressed
> (compression) if they are not already included in the preference list.
> In addition, the preferred keyserver and signature notations (if any)
> are shown.
>
> setpref string
>
> Set  the  list  of  user  ID  preferences to string for
> all (or just the selected) user IDs. Calling setpref with no arguments
> sets the preference list to the default (either built-in or set via
> --default-preference-list), and calling setpref with "none" as the argument sets an > empty preference list. Use gpg2 --version to get a
> list  of  available algorithms.  Note  that  while you can change the
> preferences on an attribute user ID (aka "photo ID"), GnuPG does not
> select keys via attribute user IDs so these preferences will not be
> used by GnuPG. When setting preferences, you should list the
> algorithms in the order which you'd like to see them used by someone
> else when encrypting a message to your key.  If  you  don't include
> 3DES,  it  will  be  automatically  added at the end.  Note that there
> are many factors that go into choosing an algorithm (for example, your
> key may not be the only recipient), and so the remote OpenPGP
> application being used to send to you may or may not follow your exact
> chosen order for a given message.  It will, however, only  choose an
> algorithm that is present on the preference list of every recipient
> key.  See also the INTEROPERABILITY WITH OTHER OPENPGP PROGRAMS
> section below.

To automate, would need to extract each key and then query prefs.